# Error in the pygame.key.get_pressed() method

Tags: python, pygame, key, space, pressed

I have no idea why the following is giving the error:  name 'K_SPACE' is not defined. Importing pygame also imports the keyboard constants which includes 'K_SPACE'.

My code:

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_SPACE]:
    pygame.quit
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just did this:

```
import pygame
```

Then you need to do this:

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    pygame.quit
```

Comment: O.P.: Another way is along with `import pygame` add a `from pygame.locals import *` line - therefore one gets only the constants on the module namespace.

Answer (score 1):

If the interpreter complains about the symbol not being defined, probably you need to fully qualify the name:

```
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    pygame.quit
```

or explicitly import it:

```
from pygame import K_SPACE
...
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_SPACE]:
    pygame.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

to the beginning of your program, this will import the key variables.